# capture optional surrounding characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I'm not that savvy in regex, so I'm not sure how to achieve the following thing:

I'd like to capture any arbitary string from an input that may or may not be surrounded by the '$' character. If a '$' character is present at the beginning of the string, the '$' character at the end must be present.

Currently I have

```
^\w+([_.-]\w+)*$
```

which roughly translates to:

1. Arbitary word characters
2. Beginning of capture group
3. any character of '_', '.', '-'
4. Before an optional \n

So valid matches would be:

```
test
test-5
test.1.3
test-alpha.2
```

Now I'd like to make this possible

```
$test$
```

But not...

```
$test (or test$)
```

Comment: I don't see the `Before an optional \n` in the regex :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:\w+(?:[_.-]\w+)*)|\$test\$)$
```

Its better to add that with `|` instead off modifying the original one.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/32

Comment: I would have replicated the `^...$` instead of using the non-capturing group, but that is my style. I DO think that for `$test$` he meant "the full pattern" and not simply $**test**$

Comment: @xanatos dat  will require a small change provided OP clarifies it :)

Comment: @vks Yes, I meant the full patern, including "$" ;)

Comment: @user4614918 `^(?:(?:\w+(?:[_.-]\w+)*)|\$\w+([_.-]\w+)*\$)$`